# Efficient way of showing Datatables in loop

Tags: shiny, dt

I have a dataset in which there is a variable named "Variables". I want to display tables in shiny app of each unique value of column "Variables". See the snapshot of image below. I am using it via **lapply( )**. It works fine. But it takes some time to show tables as I have close to 20 tables. Each table has close to 15 columns. Is there any better way to do it in loop other than lapply( ).

[image]

```
stratsgroups <- Detailed %>% distinct(Variables) %>% pull()

    observe({
      
      lapply(stratsgroups, function(x) {
        
        output[[paste0('T_', x)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
          
          # Data Preparation
          data() %>% dplyr::filter(Variables == x) %>% select(2:(ncol(Detailed)-2)) %>% 
            rename(!!x := !!sym("Categories"))  %>% 
            
            
          # ==============
          # DT Option
          # ==============
          
          datatable(rownames=FALSE,
                    extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedColumns'), selection = 'none',
                    options = list(
                      columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = '_all')),
                      paging = T, 
                      pageLength = 10, 
                      searching = FALSE, 
                      ordering=F, 
                      info = F,
                      dom = 'Bfrtip',
                      scrollX = TRUE,
                      fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1),
                      
                      # Callbacks
                      rowCallback = lastrow(),
                      fnDrawCallback = DTpagination(),
                      
                      # Button
                      buttons = DTmenuitems(Table_Menu, title)
                    ) )
          
        })
      })
    })

output$dt <- renderUI({
  
  tagList(lapply(stratsgroups, function(i) {
    
    box(dataTableOutput(session$ns(paste0('T_', i))), width = 12)
    
  }))
  
})
```

Comment: Not sure about speeding it up, but looking at your code, I don't think the `observe` is necessary.  `renderDataTable` will react.

Comment: Thanks. I am also applying loop in renderUI( ) and then pass 1 uioutput. It seems this is the issue. Can I pass the uioutput one by one (without manually entering in UI)? I updated the code for your reference